# Refreshing a div with setInterval but it disturbs the template of view page

Tags: javascript, .net, model-view-controller, jscript

I am trying to refresh a  in my MVC view page that displays data from database using the following code:

```html
<div id="stuDetails" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div id="AttendanceStatus" class="ts-intro">
        <h2 class="into-sub-title">Live Attendance</h2>
        <h3 class="into-title">&#40;@DateTime.Now&#41;</h3>

        <table class="mu-blog-caption table">
            @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows) {
            <tr style="background-color:#30652c; color:#fff;">

                <td>
                    No. of person present in Hotel
                </td>
                <td>
                    &#58;&nbsp;@row["No_of_persons_Inn"]

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:#B73522; color:#fff;">
                <td>
                    No. of person out of the in Hotel
                </td>
                <td>
                    &#58;&nbsp;@row["No_of_persons_Out"]

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Total
                </td>
                <td>
                    &#58;&nbsp;@row["Total_persons"]

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id="lblmessage"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Absent list &raquo;</a></p>
                </td>

            </tr>
            }
        </table>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            setInterval("refresh();", 1000);
        });

        function refresh() {
            $("#AttendanceStatus").load("#AttendanceStatus");
    </script>
```

Although it refreshes the page and displays the desired results but it disturbs the template and display whole page within the  to be refreshed and I am getting the result as in the screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qlGc.png)

instead of this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTCYc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Razor I guess? It's server rendered. You could try to reload the whole page every 30 seconds:

```
function refresh() { setTimeout(function() { location.reload(); }, 30000); }
```

When client side refresh is needed try to build your table in Javascript and append it to the dom. Hope it helps!

Comment: mine requirement is to get the values after every 5 seconds. Although its working fine, but it disturbs the template by displaying extra content in div after being refreshed as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Ok, change interval to 5000 then and you could wrap you 'AttendanceStatus'-table with an `<iframe>` when you want to stick to server-side rendering.

The screenshot is not very clear to me. What do you exactly mean by 'disturbs' What is that extra content?

   **BTW**: you are missing a closing bracket at the end `}` of your `refresh()` function

Comment: By word distrub i means, the Live content has to be on left side of our values heading, but it push the whole template into the  div  section along with the Live content. The closing } is there but i missed it while posting.

Comment: Ok, and you also noticed a closing `</div>` tag is missing?